# sscanf formatted input in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code which works if there are no spaces in the input string.

```
char* input2 = "(1,2,3)";
sscanf (input2,"(%d,%d,%d)", &r, &n, &p);
```

This fails for the following input:

```
char input2 = " ( 1 , 2 , 3  ) ";
```

How to fix this?

Comment: all scanf functions will treat space as an input  termination character, if u want to skip space then put space wherever you need to skip it

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix: add spaces in the pattern.

```
char* input2 = "( 1 , 2 , 3 )";
sscanf (input2,"( %d, %d, %d )", &r, &n, &p);
```

The spaces in the pattern consume any amount of whitespace, so you're fine. Test program:

```
        const char* pat="( %d , %d , %d )";
        int a, b, c;

        std::cout << sscanf("(1,2,3)", pat, &a, &b, &c) << std::endl;
        std::cout << sscanf("( 1 , 2 , 3 )", pat, &a, &b, &c) << std::endl;
        std::cout << sscanf("(1, 2 ,3)", pat, &a, &b, &c) << std::endl;
        std::cout << sscanf("(  1 , 2 ,   3 )", pat, &a, &b, &c) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
3
3
3
3
```

This behaviour is because of the following paragraph from the manual:

```
A directive is one of the following:

·      A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.;
       see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space,
       including none, in the input.
```